# Sharepoint 2010 missing webparts

Tags: web-part

I set up a sharepoint farm and everything works ok; but when I am trying to add new webparts to a webpart page I get only a small list. Like this:

[screenshot of german webparts](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f618fae823.png)

If you compare this with this list:

[screenshot of english webparts](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4ed76765a5.png)

I have installed language packs for german and italian and the main page is in german. May that be the problem?

Or does anybody know from where I can get these webparts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem. I deleted the site collection and created a new one. The language of the site collection has to be English. After that I enabled in the central administration that the users can select a language and on the site collections lanaugage properties I enabled "german" and "italian" language. With this I have all english webparts, but I, or better the user, can change the language of the page.

Comment: Its unfortunate but a lot of the built in web parts only seem to have the 1033 (En-US) language versions.

Comment: Well I could live with that, if they would at least show up in the german version too!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple web front ends? I think the language packs need to be installed on each.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288518.aspx

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I have sharepoint on a single server where there is also the IIS which hosts the webpages. I installed the language pack only on that server.
I tried now to create a new web application with an english site collection and there are all the webparts... are they simply missing in german or what is going on here?